# Installing es6-promise with typings

Tags: angularjs, typescript, es6-promise

I was reading this article on Angular 2 - https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-angular-2-with-webpack
* the above article is for Angular 2 RC5.

All works smoothly until the time we get to executing this line - installing es6-promise with typescript (typings).:
./node_modules/.bin/typings install es6-promise --save

Executing this line in Terminal throws the following error:

typings WARN hastypings Typings for "es6-promise" already exist in "node_modules/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts". You should let TypeScript resolve the packaged typings and uninstall the copy installed by Typings
typings ERR! message Unable to find "es6-promise" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message However, we found "es6-promise" for 2 other sources: "common" and "dt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this same issue
The command has been changed to:

```
typings install dt~es6-shim --save --global
```

You can check this github issue for reference:
[Unable to install es6 Shim or registry:env/meteor](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/517)

Comment: Does it have to be global now? Or is it just a preference of yours?

Comment: @KonradViltersten, no it does not need to be global, was just my preference at that instance

Comment: Awesome! This helped me on windows, where i had a "typings" script in my package.json:

"typings": "./node_modules/.bin/typings",

and i ran the command:

> npm run-script typings -- install dt~es6-shim --save --global

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you already have typings installed with the module, so there is no need еo do it manually. Try just to skip this step - `./node_modules/.bin/typings install es6-promise --save`

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

./node_modules/.bin/typings install es6-promise --source dt --save

It will import for you the requested file from DefinitelyTyped.

Answer (score 0):

With the `typings` repo being [deprecated](https://github.com/typings/typings), you would now use the following command:

`npm install @types/es6-shim --save`